# MdTable inside component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can I create an angular component with `<md-table>` inside and pass `<md-table>` content elements (like `<md-header-row>`, `<md-header-cell>`, etc.)?

I tried to do it with `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="...">` or with `<ng-content>` and `<md-table>` throws errors because it doesn't find the elements.

[Plunker Code Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/RpOncq9lbwPcjAGjXSyR?p=preview)

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Comment: I want to create a general component with md-table and some permanent additions (like filters, columns)

Comment: you should put your table in the `table-component` and pass the parameters as `@Input`

Comment: And then use `ngFor` to create the `<md-header-cell>` and `<md-cell>` elements? How can i pass pipes for each column with `@Input`?

Comment: you want it as a generic reusable component right? and your dataSource remains same i.e. the headers remain same and you want to add the entire table code in every component ?

Comment: No, my dataSource no remains the same, only a few properties (3 or 4 properties).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154144/discussion-between-leibale-eidelman-and-faisal).

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `ng-content` :

```
<myComponentWithDataTable>
    <md-header-row></md-header-row>
</myComponentWithDataTable>
```

In your component :

```
<md-table>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</md-table>
```

Comment: I forgot to note that i tried with `<ng-content>` too (as you can see in the plunker).

Comment: Oh I didn't see the plunkr ! I'll play arround with it and let you know what I found

Comment: Please let me know even if you didn't find a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't find a solution, sorry ... It seems your only way is to reunite all tags in one component :/

Comment: Can you think on other way to create component/directive/whatever for what i need?

Comment: A generic one yes, probably, you could for instance pass your headers to a component like so `[{header: 'name', prop: 'name'}]`, pass your data along, and make a ngFor each column, that will fetch the correct property in the data. Was that clear ?

Comment: But in this way i cannot pass pipes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154145/discussion-between-leibale-eidelman-and-trichetriche).